# Как работает reinterpret_cast?

Tags: c++, type-conversion

```
struct foo {
    int a = 1;
};

struct bar {
    int b = 2;
};

struct baz : foo, bar {
    int c = 3;
};


int main() {
    baz oBaz;
    auto s_cast = static_cast<foo*>(&oBaz);
    auto r_cast = reinterpret_cast<bar*>(&oBaz);
    std::cout << s_cast->a << std::endl;
    std::cout << r_cast->b << std::endl;
}
```

Как в данном случае работает *reinterpret_cast*? Почему на консоли я вижу 1, 1?

Comment: А что вы ожидали увидеть и почему? Как работает `reinterpret_cast` можно прочитать в каком-нибудь учебнике, не перепечатывать ведь нам объяснение. Лучше объясните, какое у вас сейчас понимание.

Comment: При разыменовании `r_cast` получаете неопределенное поведение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что при этом приведении никакое наследование никак не используется. Просто кусок памяти объявляется содержащим то `baz`, то `bar` — один и тот же кусок, заметим.

Из-за конкретного размещения `baz` в памяти (начиная с `foo`) и поскольку вся структура `bar` из одного числа, это число в памяти от `foo` и выступает то в роли `baz.a`, то `bar.b`.

Никакой гарантии именно такого размещения нет, как сказал user7860670, это неопределенное поведение.